# Automatic higher kinded type inference within generic methods

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-inference, higher-kinded-types

I'm struggeling a bit with higher kinded types and complilers type inference...
I do have the following classes:

```
sealed trait Foo[A] {
  @JsonProperty val payload : List[A] = Nil
}

class Baa    extends Foo[MyCoolClassOne]
class FooBaa extends Foo[MyCoolClassTwo]
```

Now i have a function, that calls a REST-API to get either a JSON-response representing Baa or FooBaa (or other subclasses of Foo, just mention 2 of them for this example).

```
def getContent[A, F <: Foo[A]](url: String) : List[A] = {
    // call API
    // use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper to deserialize
    // psuedo code...
    val response = mapper.readValue(responseFromAPI, classTag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[F]])
    return response.payload
}
```

I could then call the API to get my content:

```
def getBaa(urlToBaa:String) = getContent[MyCoolClassOne, Baa](urlToBaa)
```

or

```
def getFooBaa(urlToFooBaa:String) = getContent[MyCoolClassTwo, FooBaa](urlToFooBaa)
```

### The question

Why do i need to pass both classTags to funtion getContent?
**How can i avoid this**?

#### My thoughts

Foo is a sealed trait. There are (in this example) only 2 classes extending it. Both classes are extending Foo with a specific type. Why is the compiler unable to infer the type correct, if i would define the function somethign like this:

```
def getContent[F <: Foo[A]](url: String) : List[A] = { ... }
```

i know, that the compiler will look for a class 'A' in this case. But how could i tell him, that it is the typeinformation of the subclass of Foo.

Or to be more precise, i don't care about the method declaration, but to pass an 'obvious' typeinformation to the function, each time i call it, is very annoing.

Comment: If you write `def getA[F <: Foo[A]] : List[A]= {...}`, you have an unbound type variable `A` on the right hand side, so how is it "redundant"?

Comment: in the case you described, its not redundant. but in the "first2 case i mentioned: 
`def getA[A, F <: Foo[A]] : List[A] = {...}`
so if have [**A**, F<Foo[**A**]] ... the **A** two times...

Comment: You have exactly one `A` in the return type, and exactly one declaration of `A` on the left hand side. The only redundancy I see is the `F <: Foo[A]`, which then isn't used anywhere, neither for the arguments, nor for the return type. If it's not needed, why don't you just drop `F` and define it as `get[A]: List[A] = { ... }`? Now that definitely doesn't look "redundant" any more, or does it?

Comment: Could it be that you wanted to make `Foo` into a typeclass or a `CanBuildFrom`-like construct or something similar?

Comment: This sounds to me like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Perhaps if you share the actual problem you're trying to solve we'd be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: ok. thanks for the feedback. maybe i was not able to simplify my 'problem'. i edited my question, with the 'real' problem...